# where to store data in Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I hope to migrate one of my windows app to mac.

As we know, on vista/win7, there are public data directories that one app can add, save and delete data files **without RAC permission**.

Are there same directories on Mac/Cocoa?

or

I can store the data to any directory without any problem and any permission?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Make sure you don't hard code the paths that you do use, use the APIs to locate them. For example, this will return an array containing the application support folder path: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)`

Comment: Also, NSFileManager has an equivalent method that returns an NSURL object (increasingly the way forward for modern file-system access). It also does away with the array, which nobody really used, so it's slightly easier.

Comment: If you develop for the Mac, you should read the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html). It also mentions this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, by default, unless you enable sand-boxing, write to any directory the user has access to. Generally though, Cocoa apps store data in the user's home directory in `~/Library/Application Support/<your-app-name>`

Comment: +1 as I can't stand apps that store it in the documents directory (like Microsoft Office and Autodesk Maya).

Comment: The HIG mentions specifically that the Documents folder is only for files created by the user. Any files your application *implicitly* creates (including, but by no means limited to, the database for a “shoebox” [iPhoto/iTunes-style] app) should go somewhere in Library. The HIG gives more specific guidance on this and many other topics.

Answer (score 8):

These are the 3 you can write to:

`~/Library/Application Support/app-identifier`

`~/Library/app-identifier`

`~/Library/Caches/app-identifier`

(replace app-identifer with your app identifier)

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572) under "File-System Usage Requirements for the Mac App Store"